# Can you use charAt();'s to compare values in a string?

Tags: java, string-comparison

I'm writing a java code currently for class and I'm trying to figure out how to implement a run length encoding on a user input. The main problem I'm having it with comparing the first letter with the next and that letter with the next and so on to see if they're the same letter. Currently I have:

```
        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
    String s1 = reader.nextLine();

    int sum = 0;
    char ast = '*';
    //System.out.println("Run length encoded version of string: ");


    for (int counter = 0; s1.charAt(counter) <= s1.length()-1; counter++) {

        for (int j = 0; s1.charAt(counter) == s1.charAt(j)+1; j++) {

            sum++;
            counter++;

        }

        if (sum >= 4) {

            System.out.print(ast + s1.charAt(counter) + sum);

        }

        else {
            System.out.print(s1.charAt(counter));
        }


    }
```

I know where the big problem comes from in this and why it doesn't work but, namely from the

```
for (int j = 0; s1.charAt(counter) == s1.charAt(j)+1; j++) {

        sum++;
        counter++;

    }
```

segment as it just goes infinitely. Is there a proper way to do this? The professor mentioned it can be done without loops and while I can see it being possible I can't see it being short. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `s1.charAt(j)+1`? Why would you add one to the *character?* Did you mean to add one to the position? That would be `s1.charAt(j+1)`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And remember to always add the appropriate language tag, some people will just skip your questions otherwise.

Comment: @paxdiablo Oh, I see. I thought that it was akin to length()-1 where it would modify the position of it. You're right! Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String str="ayyusaab";
char[] ch=str.toCharArray();

for(int i=0;i<ch.length-1;i++){
   for(int j=i+1;j<ch.length-1;j++){
      if(ch[i]==ch[j]) {
         System.out.println(ch[i]+" at Index "+i +"with j at "+j);
      }
   }
}
```